# Run a windows xp bat script remotely from a ubuntu machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-xp, batch-file

Is it possible to run a windows xp bat script remotely from a ubuntu machine via command line?

Comment: This really belongs on Serverfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you have an ssh server running on the WinXP machine.  It is trivial to set  up such a server if you have installed [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  This is well described [here](http://lifehacker.com/software/home-server/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server-205090.php).

Then from an Ubuntu command line (or cron job) you run

```
ssh user@winxp command
```

Make sure your .bat has executable permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the technology you are after is [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation).  I see that there is an ubuntu package called wmi-client, which you can sudo apt-get install and attempt to you.  Some quick searches and I'm unable to find details, but maybe that will get you somewhere....

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use something like remote desktop, and if you did it that way, it would work, but your question isn't very specific