# Is it possible to run a batch script remotely on a Windows machine from Linux without installing ssh?

Tags: windows, linux

I am looking for a way in Linux to run a batch script on a remote Windows machine. I already searched some forums and the Internet and found e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095807/run-a-windows-xp-bat-script-remotely-from-a-ubuntu-machine).

It seems that the easiest way so far is using `ssh`. But do Linux or Windows also offer some built-in tools to solve this problem (something like [at-command](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) for Linux-to-Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://eol.ovh.org/winexe/). It seems to be the linux counter part to the Windows [Sysinternals PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tool.
.

Comment: Seems good, but it is also a tool that I have to install. I am looking for a built-in solution.

Comment: You do not have to install anything on the remote machine (windows). Of course, you need the tool to be present on the linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use ad-hoc services for remote execution, e.g. Nagios NRPE for windows. It is not exactly what the developers had in mind, but it can be (ab)used in this way.