# executing command on a Windows Machine from a UNIX/LINUX Machine

Tags: windows, unix, networking, ssh

is it possible to execute a command (ex: launching a .bat file located on the remote machine) on a Windows Remote Machine, using a UNIX or Linux Machine ?

Is there something like a scp/ssh mechanism or at least a way to connect to a Windows Machine passing through the network ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095807/run-a-windows-xp-bat-script-remotely-from-a-ubuntu-machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, recent Windows versions only support the [Remote Desktop protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol). As far as I know, client versions only allow a single user, while server versions with installed [Terminal Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) allow for multiple simultaneous users.

Windows Server versions also support the Telnet protocol, but the server is disabled by default - it may not even be installed. Therefore you will have to [enable it manually](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/configure-telnet-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html). Do you really want to use *Telnet* of all things, though? Just the security concerns are enough to make it mostly useless.

There is also a version of [OpenSSH for Windows](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh), that uses  the Cygwin DLL. I have not tried it, but using an SSH implementation from the Unix world does have its appeal (and probably a few disadvantages). See also [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html).

EDIT:

Recent Windows versions also support the [Windows Remote Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) system, which allows you to launch an interactive session throuh a bit of [trickery](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/WINDOWS-SERVER-2008-REVIEWED,1710-15.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Vandyke VShell](http://www.vandyke.com/products/vshell/).

Comment: Nothing exists by default inside the Windows and Linux OS instead of installing a software for it ?

Comment: To go for the secured connections, I would think so.